# Can I deploy COTS application in Openshift Container

Tags: containers, openshift

I need to migrate my on-premise applications to Openshift Containers that will be hosted in AWS IaaS environment. When looking for possibilities of hosting COTS (Commercial off the shelf) applications in Openshift Containers, I am unable to reach a solution. 
Can you please share your knowledge and if possible, any use-case, sample procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at OpenShift Primed for the Red Hat certified ISV programme:

https://hub.openshift.com/primed

Although re-reading your question it seems to be more around "can I containerise my existing application".  Which is something relatively straightforward to do technically, but you will need to check with the vendor on the support and licensing conditions for this.